# Single-backtick inline code block in jekyll, picking language

Tags: jekyll, prismjs

Jekyll supports single-backtick inline code: something like `std::vector<int> v;` gets rendered as `<code>std::vector&lt;int&gt; v;</code>`.

Is it possible to add something more to that? Is there a configuration I can do to make it render as `<code class="language-cpp">std::vector&lt;int&gt; v;</code>`? The syntax highlighter I use (Prism) doesn't get activated for the single backtick blocks - only for those which the specified language class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [kramdown block attributes](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#block-attributes) like this :

```
`std::vector<int> v;`{:.CSSClass}
```